# Windows 10: how to always use this app to open files w/o filename extension?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, file-extension, usability

When you open file w/ extension for the 1st time you see this:

[image]

When you open file w/o extension for the 1st time you see this:

[image]

So, where is "Always use this app to open files w/o filename extension"? Confused.

Example: the end user needs to open all extensionless files in a text editor. How to do that in Windows 10?

Comment: I don't see as there can be one single simple rule for an extensionless file, unless that rule is "Ask". You don't know what it is [ok, you might], the system doesn't know what it is, it may not be the same thing each time. You're trying to plan for an edge case that may not always have the same edge.

Answer (score 3):

Apps that can open a file by pointing to a file must have extensions that point to the app. There is not any way around this.

What you can do, what I do, is use Windows File Explorer to point the file, Right Click and then use the Open With selection.  That will allow you to select an app like Notepad, UltraEdit or like app.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to "Open with..." is "Send to..."

If you type `shell:sendto` in the Windows Explorer address bar, this will open the file location for the "Send to" feature. You would then place a shortcut there, named the way you want it to look in the context menu. Some programs might require a command-line switch, but the filename is sent as a parameter.

You would select the file(s), right-click for the context menu, pick "Send to". The file selected will be passed automatically to the program.

I do this with Notepad++ and it does not require any additional switches added to the target. If you select more than one text file, Notepad++ will open them all (never tested *how many* but 5 at once works).